# Is there a way to get INFORMIX-SQL 4.10 to run natively under Windows XP and higher?

Tags: informix

Is there a way to get INFORMIX-SQL 4.10 (or other versions) to run natively under Windows XP and higher?

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly — almost certainly not.

Informix SQL 4.10 was produced circa 1989.  That means it runs under DOS, not Windows.  You might, if you're really lucky, get the code to run in some DOS emulation mode, but I'd regard it as unlikely.